# C# get excel data in exponential format

Tags: c#, excel, tostring, tryparse, exponential

Excel had controlled over the formatting as explained under [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214233)

In my sample data (alphanumeric) in excel: -

P000213590-A

312700133751-- > display as 3.127E+11

In my sample code: -

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("PartUpload");

DataColumn column;

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.AllowDBNull = true;
column.ColumnName = "Part Original";
dt.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.AllowDBNull = true;
column.ColumnName = "Part_ToString";
dt.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.AllowDBNull = true;
column.ColumnName = "Part_TryParse";
dt.Columns.Add(column);

string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\seahc1\Desktop\test1.xls;Extended Properties=ImportMixedTypes=Text;Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";

OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
objConn.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT Part as [Part Original]FROM [Sheet1$]", connStr);

adap.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["Part_ToString"] = row["Part Original"].ToString();

    double doubleConverResult;
    bool result = double.TryParse(row["Part Original"].ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out doubleConverResult);
    if (result)
    {
        row["Part_TryParse"] = doubleConverResult.ToString();
    }
}
```

Part_ToString = with exponential = "3.1270013375e+011" 
Part_TryParse = round to nearest=312700133750

I debug and found that `adap.Fill(dt)` fill the datatable with data in exponential.

How can I get the exact value through the C# programs because I do not want the end user to format their excel spreadsheet.

Please advice, Thanks.

Comment: erm, what?   question doesn't make any sesne...

Comment: Clearly there is a language barrier preventing us from making sense of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I see what Crystal means.

Create an Excel document and put 312700133751 number into a cell. The formatting of the cell must be "General".

Excel will display 3.127E+11 instead of 312700133751.

The problem is that, when you read the file with the OleDbConnection driver, the DataTable will be filled with the "3.1270013505e+011" string value (even when Excel has the "General" formatting).

The problem is that 3.1270013505e+011 equals 312700133750, not 312700133751 (notice the last digit, is a zero instead of a one). This is the issue! That the OleDbConnection is "truncating" the decimals of the number up to 10 digits, which is leaving one extra digit out of the conversion.

I haven't found a solution either...